# using regular expression to find polysyllabic words

Tags: javascript, regex, nlp

i'm trying to use regexp to find the number of polysyllabic words in a piece of text, my code works most of the time but doesn't pick up on some of the poly words:

```
polySyllableCount = lWords2.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy\s]es|ed|[^laeiouy\s]e)$/, '');
```

is what I use to count the syllables, and

```
polySyllableCount = lWords2.replace(/^y/, '');
```

to replace the leading Y's so they are not counted,

and finally:

```
try 
{
polySyllables = polySyllableCount.match(/[aeiouy]\S[aeiouy]\S[aeiouy]/g).length;
}
catch(err)
{
console.log("No Poly Words")
}
```

to count the number of polysyllabic words.

My thought process is that it will find any 3 vowels in a (modified) word, separated by anything except a whitespace, to give me the number of polysyllabic words

Comment: please notice that \S also matches punctuation marks like `.` and `,` and that can be the cause of some mis-detection. You can replace \S with \w for better results. Of course \w will include numbers too and if you want to be really accurate, you may use [a-z]. Also you are using the /g switch. You need to add /i to it so that it searches for AEIOUY too so it will be /...regexp.../gi

Comment: ok thanks, that will definitely help! I'll use both [a-z] and gi

Comment: also do you know how i say that [a-z] can occur any number of times (i'll actually probably put '[^laeiouy]')

Comment: That would be [a-z]+ if at least one letter is going to happen or [a-z]* if the minimum is zero. Also you can use custom numbers like [a-z]{2,6} which means between 2 to 6 times. Learn more here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please notice that \S also matches punctuation marks like . and , and that can be the cause of some mis-detection. For example:

```
'ame.na mana miu' //'ame.na' will be treated like one word with your regexp
```

You can replace \S with \w for better results. Of course \w will include numbers too and if you want to be really accurate, you may use [a-z]. Also you are using the /g switch. You need to add /i to it so that it searches for AEIOUY too so it will be

```
/...regexp.../gi
```

You can learn more here: javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml